# Multimedia keys (Fn+[F1..F12]) don't work anymore after upgrade

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard-shortcuts, xfce, multimedia

I'm experiencing a strange issue with the multimedia keys on Archlinux with XFCE 4.

I used to change the sound level with <kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>F11</kbd>/<kbd>F12</kbd> keys but after a reboot, I'm not able to use it anymore. Moreover, I can't set new keyboard shortcut (in XFCE keyboard configuration utility) using a <kbd>Fn</kbd> key combination (where 3 days ago I've successfully set the <kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> shortcut (alias `XF86Launch6`).

However, it seems that the <kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> shortcut works and properly disable/enable Wifi network AND everything works on Gnome (volume, keybinding)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an Asus Laptop, it necessary to make : `sudo modprobe asus_nb_wmi` and everything will work from the <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys to the Wifi state LED.